# Call method after method were called c++

Tags: c++

I don't know if is possible to call a method of inherit class after parent's method were called.
Array in class A is unsorted , and my goal is to sort array but only for class B
Here is my PSEUDO CODE

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{


public:
 double *array;
 A()
 {
    array = new double[50];
 }

 void randomMethod();
 int randomMethid2();

 void add_element(double);
};

class B : public A
{
public:
 B():A(){}

private:
 void sort(void);
};


int main()
{

 return 0;
}
```

What I need is to call sort() method after adding an element : add_element();
So for example I have an object 
B b1;
and after calling
b1.add_element(5); <- adds 5 at the end of array

and after that how to sort b1 array inside of class not in main() !

Comment: Sounds like you want `add_element` to be `virtual` and override it in `B`?

Comment: As mentioned, `add_element` should be `virtual`. If you're keeping the array sorted, I might recommend insertion sort though.

Comment: You should open your C++ textbook to the chapter that explains virtual inheritance, and read it, then have the overriding method in the subclass call the overridden method in the superclass, first, then do its own job.

Comment: I add element at the end of array in A , its works same for B but what I want after adding it in B to call sort();

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Virtual *methods*, not virtual *inheritance*. The latter is definitely unnecessary here.

Comment: @Chilipepper, we know what you want … what you need is `virtual` method for `add_element`. In B's, you'd call A's, then call sort.

Comment: Yeah you are right thanks you a lot for help

Comment: But what about calling method after operator function like [] ?